# Git commit with no email

Tags: git

I'am currently converting a svn repository into a git one. As I proceed manually, I regularly change the user.name and user.email to set the author of the commit. Everything seems to work fine, but now I have to commit something from a user which has no email address. I removed email property from .gitconfig file and tried, but then in git log, email field shows `user_login@user_login.(none)`. Is it possible to set no email and prevent git guessing one ?

Comment: Are you really doing this manually? Why not write a script to do all the hard work?

Comment: Yes I am. Since svn cannot rebase multiple commits into single ones, I have to merge some commits during my conversion process, which is hard to do with script since it requires my inspection. I also translate the comments into english and format it for git (50 characters title...). So I have to do it by hand if I want it to be well done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Commit without setting user.email and user.name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058041/commit-without-setting-user-email-and-user-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git commit as different user without email / or only email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579311/git-commit-as-different-user-without-email-or-only-email)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think that you can only do this with an explicit author specification:

```
git commit --author "Snail Mail <>"
```

You need the angle brackets so that git knows that you really are passing an empty email address.

Comment: Wanted to set it up in user.name but it does not work. Only in command line.

Comment: Ok, every think now works ! Had to set:
`git config --global user.name "Snail Mail"`
`git config --global user.email \<\>`
< and > escaped because I use bash.
Thx again for your reply.

Comment: Some tools complain when having empty email fields. Wasn't it git rebase -i?

Comment: Does not work at all, I receive the same messages as without --author.

Answer (score 42):

Similar to neodelphi's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372970/git-commit-with-no-email#comment8899833_7373004), you can set this for all commits with

```
git config --global user.name 'Snail Mail'
git config --global user.email '<>'
```

(You can use quotes instead of escaping.) To set this for the current project only, remove the `--global` option only. i.e.

```
git config user.name 'Snail Mail'
git config user.email '<>'
```

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this one did.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 16):

### Use GitHub Anonymous NoReply Email *(recommended)*

When contributing to github, always use the anonymous noreply email address provided by github - which you can find here: https://github.com/settings/emails (have to tick "Keep my email addresses private" to see it).

Read more here: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address

If using github or even if you're not, this is a better option than setting no email.

```
git config user.name 'Joe Blogs'
git config user.email 'ID+username@users.noreply.github.com'
```

Or you can add this to your `${repo}/.git/config` or `.gitconfig` file directly;

```
[user]
    name = Joe Blogs
    email = ID+username@users.noreply.github.com
```

### Set invalid email *(not recommended)*

Otherwise you can fallback to the other options people have stated;

```
git config user.name 'Joe Blogs'
git config user.email '<>'
```

Or you can add this to your `${repo}/.git/config` or `.gitconfig` file directly;

```
[user]
    name = Joe Blogs
    email = <>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only adding additional information to both existing answers.

To know if this is really the true answer, let's create a commit without specifying an username and email.

```bash
git init
git config --global --unset user.name
git config --global --unset user.email
git commit -m "Initial commit" --allow-empty
```

We get this output:

```bash
[main (root-commit) f60282f] Initial commit
 Committer: Nato Boram <nato@natocorsairpopos.lan>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author
```

We see the committer (author) as `Nato Boram <nato@natocorsairpopos.lan>`, where `Nato Boram` is the name of my user profile and `nato@natocorsairpopos.lan` is the name of my user and my machine. In other words, `username <email>`.

Now if we really want to have a name and an empty email, we would end up with `username <>`, so we can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28933328/5083247).

```bash
git config user.name 'Snail Mail'
git config user.email '<>'
```

If we test it:

```bash
git commit --allow-empty -m "Snail mail test #1"
git show HEAD
```

```bash
commit 253f9d063461fb9ceace85a34d4ae1ec6a7d5a05 (HEAD -> main)
Author: Snail Mail <>
Date:   Mon Nov 20 15:36:44 2023 -0500

    Snail mail test #1
```

Success! We can also test the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7373004/5083247):

```bash
git commit --allow-empty --author "Snail Mail <>" -m "Snail mail test #2"
git show HEAD
```

```bash
commit 144baf401a0a43b2c15d3f642b04bd4eb52076c5 (HEAD -> main)
Author: Snail Mail <>
Date:   Mon Nov 20 15:38:16 2023 -0500

    Snail mail test #2
```

Success!

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue . But now I can fix it by using github no reply mail .

Go to https://github.com/settings/email and copy your no reply mail ,it would look like this `ID+username@users.noreply.github.com` .

than set this email as global email to your pc :

`git config user.email 'ID+username@users.noreply.github.com`

After this process your problem will fix