# Git Commit Author's Email changing according to the directory and/or project?

Tags: git

I work with my own projects and every-now-and-then I do some work for third-parties where I need to use their contact-information etc in commits. I usually use just global commit names etc but now I need to specify commit names and emails according to the directory. How can I do that in Git?

> **Perhaps useful relating information**
>
> 1. [What is the difference between author and committer in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755824/multiple-authors-on-the-same-git-commit)
> 2. [Git commit with no email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372970/git-commit-with-no-email)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I specify multiple users for myself in .gitconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can have a per-repository username and email address that supercedes your global settings. It will affect commits made in the current repository, but not in other repositories.

```
git config user.name "Foo Bar"
git config user.email "foo.bar@example.com"
```

You can confirm that your local information is overriding your global defaults with:

```
git config -l | fgrep user.
```

It may show multiple entries (e.g both a global and a local configuration setting), but whatever is shown *last* in the list takes precedence.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command to commit your changes

```
git commit -m "Commit message" --author "Your Name <email>"
```

Then you will be able to set the author, email explicitly for that commit.

Comment: ...no way to make this more implicit/automatic perhaps in some file? Perhaps something centralized like gitolite but just for managing commit credentials-and-contacts (not sure whether possible, well hence the q)?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to specify different author/committer name/email according to folders. You can add a line like this in your .bashrc

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ $PWD =~ ^path/to/dir.*$ ]] && { export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=email && export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=name && export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=email && export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=name; } || { unset GIT_COMMITTER_NAME && unset GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL && unset GIT_AUTHOR_NAME && unset GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL; }'
```