# Commit Without Setting User Name and Email

Tags: git

I try to `commit` like this:

```shell
git commit --author='Paul Draper <my@email.org>' -m 'My commit message'
```

but I get:

```shell
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

I can set these, but I am on a shared box, and I would have to (want to) unset them afterwards:

```shell
git config user.name 'Paul Draper'
git config user.email 'my@email.org'
git commit -m 'My commit message'
git config --unset user.name
git config --unset user.email
```

That's a lot of lines for one `commit`!

Is there shorter way?

Comment: Not really any shorter, but if you set environment variables `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` (and either the `AUTHOR` versions of the same, or use the `--author` argument as you did), that should suffice, and you won't need to `--unset`.

Comment: git config user.name "your username Here"
git config user.email user@email.com

Comment: Or, this is shorter and probably easier: `git -c user.name=... -c user.email=... commit ...`

Answer (score 174, accepted):

(This occurred to me after suggesting the long version with the environment variables—git commit wants to set both an author and a committer, and `--author` only overrides the former.)

All git commands take `-c` arguments **before** the action verb to set temporary configuration data, so that's the perfect place for this:

```
git -c user.name='Paul Draper' -c user.email='my@email.org' commit -m '...'
```

So in this case `-c` is part of the `git` command, not the `commit` subcommand.

Comment: this sounds awesome, but which version supports it? I get an "Unknown option: -c", I'm in version 1.7.1.... :'-(

Comment: @msb: Git learned `git -c` in version 1.7.2 ([missed it by that much :--:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPwrodxghrw)).

Comment: Modern git versions seem to be not supporting them anymore:

``git commit -c user.name='test bot' -c user.email='<noreply@danilopianini.org>' -m "foo: something"``

``fatal: Option -m cannot be combined with -c/-C/-F.``

`-c` now picks commit information from the provided commit.

Comment: @DaniloPianini: there's some bug-discussion on the Git maintainers' mailing list right now about things related to this and/or use with `git merge`. It seems that some recent changes broke a few things. How soon they'll be fixed, I'm not sure. However, note that you should be using `git -c ... commit -m ...`, not `git commit -c ... -m ...`. The `-c` option here is to `git`, not to `git commit`, in other words.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I had been misusing it, indeed.

Answer (score 23):

You can edit the `.git/config` file in your repo to add the following alias :

```
[alias]
  paulcommit = -c user.name='Paul Draper' -c user.email='my@email.org' commit
```

or you can do this by command line :

```
git config alias.paulcommit "-c user.name='Paul Draper' -c user.email='my@email.org' commit"
```

And then you can do :

```
git paulcommit -m "..."
```

**Remarks:**

- The idea is then to add also aliases like `jeancommit`, `georgecommit`, ... for the other users of this shared box.
- You can add this alias to your global config by editing your personal `.gitconfig` or by adding `--global` option to the command line when adding the alias.
- The alias `paulcommit` is not a short one, but it is verbose and you can in general type only `git pau`+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: No longer working in git 2.34.1

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that I use on our shared box. In `~/.bashrc`, add the following lines:

```
alias gitaspaul='alias git="git -c user.name=\"Paul Draper\" -c user.email=\"my@email.org\""'
alias gitasnone='unalias git'
```

It works as follows: when you're in a shell session, run `gitaspaul`. From that moment on, every git command until the end of the session will use your temporary credentials. When you leave the shell, the credentials are forgotten. If you want to manually forget the credentials before the end of the session, run `gitasnone`.

This is a nice solution because it's not specific to any one repo, and it sticks around until a natural end of your computing session (like closing your ssh session).

Here's what it looks like:

```
$ git commit -m "new stuff"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.

Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

$ gitaspaul
$ git commit -m "new stuff"
[master f6a17cd] new stuff
2 files changed, 28 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting, that git on linux will default to the linux user name as given in the "gecos" field in /etc/passwd. You can output this name with `grep $(whoami) /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 5`. If this field is empty you cannot commit without setting a user name but if it is not empty git will use it. So you'd have yourself as author and the system user as committer.

See https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/ident.c