# Using `git commit` in Google Cloud Container Builder

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-container-builder

How do I commit a new file to a git repo in Container Builder? The build step seems pretty straightforward:

```
{
    "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/git",
    "args": ["commit", 
            "--author=\"David\ Wynn\ <Remixer96@gmail.com>\"",
            "-am", 
            "Test post"]
}
```

... but the resulting command wraps the --author in a way that isn't valid:

```
commit "--author="David Wynn <Remixer96@gmail.com>"" -am "Test post"
```

Is there another way to pass in an author when committing? Is there an explicit "don't quote this" command for container builder?

#### Update 01

Edmund below suggests that breaking the equals sign apart should fix this, but the error for an unknown user still gets thrown. The Stack Overflow question here:

[Commit without setting user.email and user.name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058041/commit-without-setting-user-email-and-user-name)

... suggests this is because the author flag doesn't update the committer, which is required. The new long form should be something like this:

```
git -c user.name='Paul Draper' -c user.email='my@email.org' commit -m '...'
```

.... but this brings us back to the original problem because Container Builder doesn't seem able to take a space-separated argument without quoting the whole piece.

#### Update 02 (Resolved)

For some reason, git seems fine when taking quoted strings for the -c flags, and as such this now works fine in container builder. The step now looks like the following :

```
{
  "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/git",
  "args": ["-c",
          "user.name=\"David\ \Wynn\"",
          "-c",
          "user.email=\"Remixer96@gmail.com\"",
          "commit", 
          "-m", 
          "Test post"]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

As posted in the update, git apparently takes quoted string on -c flags, so this now passes in container builder without issue using the following step:

```
{
  "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/git",
  "args": ["-c",
          "user.name=\"David\ \Wynn\"",
          "-c",
          "user.email=\"Remixer96@gmail.com\"",
          "commit", 
          "-m", 
          "Test post"]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the argument into two parts (--author, value) should fix this problem. You can do this for any argument in git that the manual says should be in format "--argument=value".

```
{
    "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/git",
    "args": ["commit", 
            "--author",
            "\"David\ Wynn\ <Remixer96@gmail.com>\"",
            "-am", 
            "Test post"]
}
```

Comment: While that does create the command:
    commit --author "David Wynn <Remixer96@gmail.com>" -am "Test post"
It seems git, as provided by the cloud buidlers at gcr.io/cloud-builders/git, still chokes on it.