# why git commit --author "name" still fails to commit error "empty ident name"

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a shared folder/repo that can be accessed by several people.  So I purposely didn't setup the user.email & user.name.  However, even I specified the author through `--author`, I was still unable to commit.

How can enforce committer always specify the `--author` when they commit?

```
git commit --author "John Doe <jd@jd.com>"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <(null)>) not allowed
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058041/commit-without-setting-user-email-and-user-name

Comment: The answer to *why*, by the way—not called out separately in the duplicate I linked—is that Git not only wants to know who the *author* is, but also who the *committer* is.

Comment: Actually, I had a hacky work around.  When I did `git config user.name "something"`, then the commit worked.  It seemed that git just didn't allow empty `user.name`