# How can I commit to a shared repo without setting global credentials?

Tags: git

I have made some changes on a staging system that I want to commit.
This is a shared system so I don't want to add my own user in the config.
When I try to commit just like that, obviously I get:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
```

which I don't want to do.

When I try this

```
git commit -c author.name="username" author.email="user@domain.com"
```

I get

```
fatal: could not lookup commit author.name=username
```

When I try

```
git commit --author "user <user@domain.com>" -m "Some text"
```

I get

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
```

How can I commit my change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
git -c user.name='Chaz' -c user.email='chaz@email.org' commit -m '...'
```

this comes from here, but i guess both of you are trying to achieve the same thing.

ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058041/commit-without-setting-user-email-and-user-name)

Comment: this works, thanks, apparently the main problem here was that my colleague sent me a cmd that used author.name and author.email instead of user.name and user.email and I kept copy pasting this.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation of `git commit --help`

> --author=<author>
>
> Override the commit author. Specify an explicit author using the standard A U Thor <author@example.com> format. Otherwise <author> is assumed to be a pattern and is used to search for an existing commit by that author (i.e. rev-list --all -i --author=<author>); the commit author is then copied from the first such commit found.

After trying `git rev-list --all -i --author=""` in my own repo, I've got some commits, which means that probably

```
git commit --author="" -m "fix"
```

should work, unless your repository has no commits at all

Comment: I would like to warn everyone to use this answer carefully, as I realized that if you're not a sole contributor of this repository, then you might end up commit using name and email of another person, which is probably undesirable