# How do I remove my email from appearing in my github repo

Tags: git, github

my private email is being used when I push changes to my github repo.

I use the desktop application for github to push my changes (https://desktop.github.com/) and it started appearing after that.

I tried deleting the the repo and then renamed the repo to the same name (it's important that the repo has the same name).

[image]

it shows my email even after I commit new changes to the file, pls help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git commit with no email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372970/git-commit-with-no-email)

Comment: git is designed to be used with an email. It is possible to commit with an empty email, but it is not standard practice.

Comment: I used the git `config --list command` and it shows my email as `user.email=`, yet when I push to update the files that have my email showing, it doesn't remove my email from appearing

Comment: Try: `git config --global user.email '<>'` from the answer I linked to.